# Why does audit logging using Hibernate Interceptor hang at SocketInputStream.socketRead0?

Tags: hibernate, freeze, interceptor

This is baffling to me.  I have searched numerous forums for clues.  In the postFlush method, I open a new hibernate (v. 3.3 - also tried v.3.5) session using a distinct session factory.  I use c3p0 v. 0.9 for connection pooling.  I start a new transaction, save the auditLog object, and commit the transaction.  This works beautifully for all my entities save one.  When attempting to commit the auditLog after deleting a ChemoRegimen entity, the application hangs (this also happens with create and update).  No exception is thrown, but upon suspending the thread I find the following stack trace (this is a Swing app):

```
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Suspended)   
SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method]    
SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 129  
VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(int) line: 145  
VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(int) line: 114   
VisibleBufferedInputStream.read() line: 73  
PGStream.ReceiveChar() line: 274    
QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(ResultHandler, int) line: 1660 
QueryExecutorImpl.execute(Query[], ParameterList[], ResultHandler, int, int, int) line: 407 
Jdbc4PreparedStatement(AbstractJdbc2Statement).executeBatch() line: 2737    
NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch() line: 1723 
BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(PreparedStatement) line: 70  
BatchingBatcher(AbstractBatcher).executeBatch() line: 268   
ActionQueue.executeActions(List) line: 266  
ActionQueue.executeActions() line: 167  
DefaultFlushEventListener(AbstractFlushingEventListener).performExecutions(EventSource) line: 321   
DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(FlushEvent) line: 50  
SessionImpl.flush() line: 1027  
SessionImpl.managedFlush() line: 365    
JDBCTransaction.commit() line: 137  **[This is where I commit the auditLog]**
MomsInterceptor.postFlush(Iterator) line: 254   
DefaultFlushEventListener(AbstractFlushingEventListener).postFlush(SessionImplementor) line: 375    
DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(FlushEvent) line: 51  
SessionImpl.flush() line: 1027  
SessionImpl.managedFlush() line: 365    
JDBCTransaction.commit() line: 137  
HibernateDAO.makeTransient(Entity) line: 119    
ChemoServices.deleteChemoRegimen(ChemoRegimen, String, Session) line: 290
```

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 as the backend with the 9.0 jdbc4 driver.  The postgresql.log shows [with my comments in brackets]:

**[First, the chemo_regimen is deleted]**

```
2011-05-11 12:19:06 CDT moms postgres LOG:  00000: execute <unnamed>: delete from moms_chemo_regimen where crxreg_id=$1<BR>
```

....
**[A lot of cascaded deletes]**
...
**[Then, my transaction begins in the interceptor session]**

```
2011-05-11 12:19:06 CDT moms postgres LOG:  00000: execute S_1: BEGIN
2011-05-11 12:19:06 CDT moms postgres LOG:  00000: execute <unnamed>: select nextval ('moms_patient_change_log_seq')
```

**[The audit-log record is inserted]**

```
2011-05-11 12:19:06 CDT moms postgres LOG:  00000: execute <unnamed>: insert into moms_patient_change_log (patclog_pat_id, patclog_action, patclog_reason, patclog_date, patclog_user_name, patclog_guid, patclog_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
2011-05-11 12:19:06 CDT moms postgres DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '17108', $2 = 'Deleted ChemoRegimen ABVD', $3 = NULL, $4 = '2011-05-11 12:19:06.813', $5 = 'daver', $6 = 'BFAA9D91-7A4E-835E-7A57-B72B2A79A4F1', $7 = '520'
```

And that is it.  The audit-log insert transaction never completes. The transaction to delete the chemo-regimen also is never committed. I am able to perform CRUD on ChemoRegimen fine when not auditing it.  A snippet of the ChemoRegimen entity is below:

```
public class ChemoRegimen extends MOMSEntity implements Auditable
{
  public static final String UNSCHEDULED = "UNSCHEDULED";

  private Date date = new Date();
  private Patient patient;
  private WorkingProtocol protocol;
  private Physician approvingPhysician;
  private boolean canChangeCycles;
  private List<ChemoEncounter> chemoEncounters = new ArrayList<ChemoEncounter>();
  private boolean complete;
  private Icdm icdm;<BR>
  ...<BR>
}
```

This is my interceptor:

```
public class MomsInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor
{
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( MomsInterceptor.class.getName() );
  private static Configuration configuration;
  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

//Create the initial SessionFactory from the default configuration files
  static
  {
    initSessionFactory();
  }

  public static void initSessionFactory()
  {
    try
    {
      configuration = new Configuration().configure();
      sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch ( Throwable ex )
    {
      // We have to catch Throwable, otherwise we will miss
      // NoClassDefFoundError and other subclasses of Error
      logger.severe( "Building SessionFactory failed - " + ex.getMessage() );
      System.err.println( "Building SessionFactory failed - " + ex.getMessage() );
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError( ex.getMessage() );
    }
  }

  private Set<Auditable> inserts = new HashSet<Auditable>();
  private Set<UpdatedEntity> updates = new HashSet<UpdatedEntity>();
  private Set<Auditable> deletes = new HashSet<Auditable>();
  private boolean audit;

  public MomsInterceptor(boolean audit)
  {
    super();
    this.audit = audit;
  }

  private class UpdatedEntity
  {
    private Auditable auditable;
    private String[] propertyNames;
    private Object[] currentState;
    private Object[] previousState;
    private Type[] types;

    public UpdatedEntity( Auditable auditable, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState )
    {
      super();
      this.auditable = auditable;
      this.propertyNames = propertyNames;
      this.currentState = currentState;
      this.previousState = previousState;
      this.types = types;
    }

    public Auditable getAuditable()
    {
      return auditable;
    }

    public String[] getPropertyNames()
    {
      return propertyNames;
    }

    public Object[] getCurrentState()
    {
      return currentState;
    }

    public Object[] getPreviousState()
    {
      return previousState;
    }

    public Type[] getTypes()
    {
      return types;
    }

    /**
     * Return the previous value of the property name prop or null if the property name is not found.
     * @param prop
     * @return
     */
    public Object getPrevious( String prop )
    {
      int i = 0;
      for ( String name : propertyNames )
      {
        if ( prop.equals( name ) )
          return previousState[i];
        i++;
      }

      return null;
    }
  }

  public boolean onSave( Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types ) throws CallbackException
  {
    boolean modified = false;
    if ( entity instanceof MutableEntity ) // Update create info.
    {
      MutableEntity me = (MutableEntity)entity;
      int i = findPropertyNameIndex( "createUser", propertyNames );
      if ( i >= 0 )
        state[i] = SessionController.userName;
      i = findPropertyNameIndex( "modifyUser", propertyNames );
      if ( i >= 0 )
        state[i] = SessionController.userName;
      modified = true;

      if ( audit && entity instanceof Auditable ) 
        inserts.add( (Auditable)entity );
    }

    return modified;
  }

  private int findPropertyNameIndex( String name, String[] propertyNames )
  {
    int i = -1;
    if ( propertyNames.length == 0 )
      return i;

    for ( String p : propertyNames )
    {
      i++;
      if ( p.equals( name ) )
        return i;
    }

    return -1;
  }

  public boolean onFlushDirty( Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types )
      throws CallbackException
  {
    boolean modified = false;

    if ( entity instanceof MutableEntity ) // Update modify info.
    {
      MutableEntity me = (MutableEntity)entity;
      int i = findPropertyNameIndex( "modifyUser", propertyNames );
      if ( i >= 0 )
        currentState[i] = SessionController.userName;
      i = findPropertyNameIndex( "modifyDate", propertyNames );
      if ( i >= 0 )
        currentState[i] = new Date();
      modified = true;

      if ( audit && entity instanceof Auditable )
        updates.add( new UpdatedEntity( (Auditable)entity, propertyNames, types, currentState, previousState ) );
    }

    return modified;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDelete( Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types )
  {
    if ( audit && entity instanceof Auditable )
      deletes.add( (Auditable)entity );
  }

  @Override
  public void postFlush( Iterator iterator ) throws CallbackException
  {
    if ( inserts.isEmpty() && deletes.isEmpty() && updates.isEmpty() )
      return;

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.setFlushMode( FlushMode.COMMIT );
    session.beginTransaction();

    try
    {
      String action = null;
      for ( Auditable entity : inserts )
      {
        action = "Created " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + entity.toString();
        session.save( new PatientChangeLog( entity.getPatient(), action, entity.getReason(), SessionController.userName ) );
      }
      for ( Auditable entity : deletes )
      {
        action = "Deleted " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + entity.toString();
        session.save( new PatientChangeLog( entity.getPatient(), action, entity.getReason(), SessionController.userName ) );
      }
      for ( UpdatedEntity entity : updates )
      {
        Auditable a = entity.getAuditable();
        StringBuffer actionBuf = new StringBuffer( "Updated " + a.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + a.toString() + ": changed " );
        int count = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < entity.getPropertyNames().length; i++ )
        {
          String prop = entity.getPropertyNames()[i];
          Type type = entity.getTypes()[i];
          Object curValue = entity.getCurrentState()[i];
          Object prevValue = entity.getPreviousState()[i];

          //Don't consider the id field or the metadata fields.
          if ( prop.equals( "id" ) || prop.equals( "createUser" ) || prop.equals( "createDate" ) || prop.equals( "modifyUser" ) 
              || prop.equals( "modifyDate" ) || prop.equals( "guid" ) )
            continue;

          if ( prevValue == null )
            prevValue = new String( "" );
          if ( curValue == null )
            curValue = new String( "" );
          if ( !prevValue.equals( curValue ) )
          {
            if ( count > 0 )
              actionBuf.append( " and " );
            actionBuf.append( prop ).append( " from '" ).append( prevValue ).append( "' to '" ).append( curValue ).append( "'" );
            count++;
          }   
        }

        Patient p = (Patient)entity.getPrevious( "patient" );  //In case the patient is changed, tie it to the previous patient.
        session.save( new PatientChangeLog( p, actionBuf.toString(), a.getReason(), SessionController.userName ) );
      }

      session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch ( HibernateException e )
    {
      try
      {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
      }
      catch ( Exception hex )
      {
        throw new RuntimeException( hex );
      }
      throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
    finally
    {
      inserts.clear();
      updates.clear();
      deletes.clear();
      session.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unable to find suitable documentation to use Hibernate events in lieu of Envers, I decided to move the code from `MyInterceptor.postFlush()` to `MyInterceptor.afterTransactionCompletion()`.  This way the current transaction was committed before I opened a new session/transaction for the audit log record.  Thanks for your help in getting this far.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly looks like a deadlock between transactions: audit transaction waits for some resources locked by the main transactions, but the main transaction cannot commit since execution of interceptor is blocked.

Perhaps it would be more conceptually clean to execute audit actions in the same transaction, though mechanism of `Interceptor`s doesn't allow it. You can try to use [events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html#objectstate-events) instead - at least, Envers uses them for audit actions.

Comment: Thanks axtavt and @SteveHall.  I will look into hibernate events.

Comment: axtavt, do you know of any documentation on using events to implement audit logging without resorting to Envers?  Envers would require major Hibernate-related changes since we do not use annotations.  I have been unable to find any documentation like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have a deadlock in the database between the auditing transaction and the Chemo transaction.